# "git pull" returns error in Windows command prompt

Tags: git, command-prompt

Now I have a git repository on a Windows machine, and would like to run automatic tests on this repository with Perl. To make sure that every time I launch the test the repository is the latest, I use:

```
system("git pull");
```

before the test.

But it returns an error:

```
fatal: Uh oh. Your system reports no Git commands at all.
```

However, when I run `git show` with the same methodology, like:

```
system("git show");
```

The output is OK, which is to say Windows command prompt recognized the `git` command (and it does exist in system PATH). So why some of the git commands could succeed while the others can't?

PS: I'm using `Git Bash`, if I launch the Perl script from git bash, both `git pull` and `git show` work. But my expectation is to double click the perl script to run it instead of calling it from `Git Bash` shell.

Comment: how does you system find git when you run `git pull`? Did you add it to your `PATH`?

Comment: @Chronial Yes I added it in the system PATH. Otherwise `git show` would also fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure this isn't a path issue, as explained in [this link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/14008)  (for windows, but valid for other OS too).
Check also if you don't have any active git alias which might prevent a git pull to work properly.

Regarding the path issue, the [OP aladine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306103/aladine)  confirms in the comments:

```
I discover that after I reinstall git, it works as normal.
```

Answer (score 1):

[The link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.msysgit/14008) in the answer of @lord_linus helped a lot to solve my problem, but I would like to make it more clear.

Indeed it's a path problem. Since I hope to use `git` command with the Command Prompt of Windows, I added the git command path (for me it's `D:\Git\Bin`) to `PATH` in environment variables.

Now in `Git Bash` there're two `git` commands:

```
$ which git
git is /bin/git
git is /Bin/git
```

And in Command Prompt there's one `git` command:

```
C:\>where git
D:\Git\bin\git.exe
```

I think that messed up the paths. My solution is to use `D:\Git\bin\git.exe` instead of `git`, so in my Perl script I wrote:

```
my $git = `where git`;
system("$git pull");
```

This work around could work as I expect.